# JSTL String Equals

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

How to check two strings in JSTL ? 
Is it `<c:if test="${dtmplOnlyCategory == dtmplDetails }">` or `<c:if test="${dtmplOnlyCategory} == ${dtmplDetails }">` . I want to check if both are string are equal if equal I have a logic to proceed

```
<c:if test="${not empty DTmpl}">
<div class="tmpcntr">
<%=onl_cat %>
<c:forEach  var="dtmplOnlyCategory" items="${onl_cat}"  varStatus="indexMap">
    <div><c:out value="${dtmplOnlyCategory }"/><br></div>

    <c:forEach var="dtmplDetails" items="${DTmpl}" varStatus="indexMap">
        <c:if test="${dtmplOnlyCategory}">
        <c:set var="tmplName" value="${dtmplDetails.tmplName}"/>
            <div class="thumbcntr" onclick="showTemplatePreview('<c:out value="${tmplId}"/>','DT','template');">
            <img src="<c:out value='${imgPath}'/>/images/<c:out value="${tmplName}"/>.gif" alt="<c:out value="${tmplName}"/>">
            <div class="tmpnme"><c:out value="${tmplName}"/></div>
            </div>
            </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach >
</div>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<c:if test="${dtmplOnlyCategory == dtmplDetails}">` is the right syntax to use